# Python: It does not let me use Tkinter root = Tk() error

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am quite new to Python, but know the basics. I have been watching a few tutorials about `Tkinter`, but even from the start when I type:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
```

It gives me the error:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/$Name/Desktop/PycharmProjects/untitled/Tkinter.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Tkinter import *
  File "/Users/$Name/Desktop/PycharmProjects/untitled/Tkinter.py", line 3, in <module>
    root = Tk()
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

I've tried different things, and I have used `IDLE`, and it still does not work. I am also on Mac OS X El Capitan if that should matter.

Comment: It's a good idea to put `my` in front of all your file names and variable names when you are starting out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You named your file `Tkinter.py`. So you are importing your own file. Rename your python file, delete `Tkinter.pyc` and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked

```
import tkinter as tk    
root = tk.Tk()
```